# Why increasing the number of reducers increases the time for running reduce phase?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I ran my Hadoop program on AWS today with different number of reducers, however what I observed is as the number of reducers increases, the time, instead of decreases, increases. For time, I mean from Map 100%, Reduce 30% to Map 100%, Reduce 100%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that the data need to be sent across the network to the reducers, if you output data from the mapper are not so big to increase the number of reducers could hit the performance as, results need to be transferred to different reducers, the I/O operations are increased as you need to create more files as each reducer create its own file.

Each reduce need to start up and be created/instantiated in the nodes, which result in an increase of startup time. Also, data need to be split across the entire number of reducers which require more network transfer time and parsing time.

Also, there is a best practice to set the number of reducers to zero, if you are not using as Hadoop does not need to worry about create them and the entire process will be faster

Reference from [yahoo developer](https://web.archive.org/web/20161109225939/https://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/hadoop/apache-hadoop-best-practices-anti-patterns-465.html)

> The efficiency of reduces is driven by a large extent by the
>   performance of the shuffle.
>
> The number of reduces configured for the application (r) is,
>   obviously, a crucial factor.
>
> Having too many or too few reduces is anti-productive:
>
> Too few reduces cause undue load on the node on which the reduce is scheduled — in extreme cases, we have seen reduces processing over
>   100GB per-reduce. This also leads to very bad failure-recovery
>   scenarios, since a single failed reduce, has a significant, adverse,
>   impact on the latency of the job.
>
> Too many reduces adversely affects the shuffle crossbar. Also, in extreme cases it results in too many small files created as the output
>   of the job — this hurts both the NameNode and performance of
>   subsequent Map-Reduce applications who need to process lots of small
>   files.

Comment: Thanks for your enlightening answer!!